# Angular JS rendering partial from different module

Tags: angularjs, module, render, partial

Hello experienced lamp / ror /ios dev . complete mean stack super noob here.

background:

I want to render SignUp partial in home

home dir is under Core Module with home Controller
sign up is under Users Module with AuthenticationController

used MEANJS boilerplate scaffolding with Yeoman

---

I initially put my form inside home.client.view.html but it is not modular want to keep the Signup with Users module

here is my sad attempt

```
<section data-ng-controller="AuthenticationController">
     <div data-ng-include data-ng-src="signup.client.view.html"></div>
</section>
```

inside the core client I added users module as so

```
ApplicationConfiguration.registerModule('core');
ApplicationConfiguration.registerModule('users');
```

what am i doing wrong

please do not link the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to put your template's source in a quotation marks (this example defines the source immediately on the ng-include part):

```
<div data-ng-include="'signup.client.view.html'"></div>
```

Here is a [Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/h9F6r13u8qDPtqJ9HAX2?p=preview).

Comment: You are welcome! B.T.W, If this is the answer you were looking for, you should mark it (this way it won't show as an open question)

Comment: I just did thanks again. Another weekend of hacking on it makes me rly udnerstand the concept of front end frame work thanks!